# Caching as a service

Tags: web-services, caching, distributed-caching

Is anyone aware of any caching-as-a-service offerings? Essentially, grab an SDK in your favorite language, an API key, and read and write from the cache service?

Something like:

```
cache = new Cache;

// read from the cache
cache->get( api_key, cache_key );

// write to the cache
cache->set( api_key, cache_key, data, expiration );
```

I've searched around and haven't found anything like this. I'm just curious more than anything.

Comment: Amazon S3 and a zillion others.  Voting to close as not constructive since this is actually a shopping list question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps memcached will do the trick:

http://blog.couchbase.com/memcached-144-windows-32-bit-binary-now-available

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memcached

UPDATE

http://aws.amazon.com/elasticache/

Comment: Hi @Marco. You're spot on with the caching concept, but that's not quite what I'm asking. :) What I'm trying to find out is whether or not an online service already exists that supports client caching via an API call. It would most likely be something like an enterprise level paid service.

Comment: Ok sorry, well I am not sure if there is one out there already.

Comment: Ah. Now that fits my description. +1. :)